# Distributed Sliding Window in Java

Tags: algorithm, distributed-computing, partitioning, sliding-window, automaton

How would you design a distributed sliding window algorithm in Java? I have an automaton for pattern detection. It is either in accepting state or invalidates.

Say the pattern I'm looking for is age: 20 followed by age: 30. The pattern is a LinkedList with two values (20, 30). The automaton accepts one record at a time. It keeps the state of the LinkedList to know how much of it matches so far. It accepts one record at a time and when the record matches LinkedList[i] it does i++. Otherwise, it invalidates which means i=0.

The automaton will have all records flow through it and reliably identify all patterns of 20 followed by 30.

It gets more complicated when the automaton gets called from a sliding window. The sliding window is time-based. When first called, it is set a certain duration, for example 10 seconds. The window saves current timestamp and every time it calls the automaton it first checks the saved timestamp against current time. If it is older than 10 seconds, the window resets the timestamp and also invalidates the automaton [because whatever in the automaton matches is possibly older than 10 seconds. I say possibly because in some cases it will be just some records in the window that are older while other records are OK, but the state gets invalidated nevertheless. The window is an approximation].

Now, the real challenge is to exploit multiple PCs to find patterns in data using the sliding window and the automaton. I found many papers that mention algorithms, for example here http://www.softnet.tuc.gr/~minos/Papers/vldbj15.pdf, but I want to reuse an existing algorithm for a distributed time-based sliding window with pattern detection (or with other automaton).

How would you design it, or could you suggest any algorithm in Java? Basically, the scenario is that there is a lot of data arriving at high speeds and hence multiple PCs need to be used. The data need to be partitioned on multiple nodes and those nodes need to successfully detect patterns.

Alternatively, any answer will be accepted that implements any distributed sliding window algorithm in Java or other language.

Comment: Time series... Window... SQL has windowing functions... Apache spark is parallelized in Java

Comment: careful, time series is a different concept not mentioned here and unrelated to the question. Yes, SQL implementations often have some windows (sliding, tumbling, jumping, ...) and Spark specifically has a SlidingRDD which leverages scala and its .sliding() function for a sliding window. But I need to know how to design an algorithm in Java that will be a distributed sliding window. Spark transforms an existing RDD into a SlidingRDD by calling .sliding(time). I do not have an RDD. I have a List<String,String> which I need to both parallelize and make sliding at the same time.

Comment: SparkContext.parallelize takes a collection to an RDD

Comment: Yes, Spark slices data, so that each node gets an equal portion. Then it offers an abstraction that makes it look like one collection. But that collection has for example 4 partitions. Then spark makes a sliding window out of that abstract collection. But it is a size-constrained window, for example 1000 events. I cannot see how to put time constraints of the window in spark to keep processing for example 10 seconds of the stream. I must be missing something. https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/mllib/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/mllib/rdd/SlidingRDD.scala

Comment: You seem to have a good understanding of what Spark/Scala does (not exactly sure why you need a Java solution if you're reading Scala code). So, if you're sure that's not the tool for the job, then my main point was that it's distributed

Comment: I found a solution for time-based sliding windows, for example a window that retains 3 seconds of the stream. Spark does not have this feature. The feature can be designed by making each node responsible for maintaining its own sliding window. For example, node 1 maintains the last 3 seconds, node 2 maintains the last 3 seconds, etc. When any of the nodes is asked to execute an operation on the partition it holds, the node makes sure it invalidates any data that has already expired before it returns the result. Spark implements lineage / it might be recomputing stuff / too slow for the window.

Comment: the solution requires an architecture that is fast, i.e. data is pushed or pulled without much recomputation. If recomputed, it could take too long and then the data would be invalidated / expired before the transformation is processed. Any ideas on other distributed architecture that can, unlike Spark, do a good job? I'm thinking of Storm. Surely, Storm can do it. https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/14171/windowing-and-state-checkpointing-in-apache-storm.html  Only, I don't understand how Storm partitions data. Do I have to split the stream manually using my own Bolt, cricket_007?

Comment: I don't know Storm. Feel free to create a new post rather than ask a new question in the comments